# Need to get List of C++ Kernel Types?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, kernel, dbghelp

Respectfully!!

I need complete list of kernel types such as "CRITICAL_SECTION", "_LARGE_INTEGER" or "_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES". Basically I am extracting all the data members of class given class name as type from some debugging SDK (right now using DIA SDK or DbgHelp) .

Now If a type(say class or struct) contains some kernel level objects like I mentioned above, it extract(details of that type e.g data member and their types ) those types as well.

I need to block extraction of kernel level objects and types. Only I need those types which are User defined and those contains only data members having native types of again some user defined types (like int, float, double ,char,std::string or can be SomeUDT obj).

Is there any other way out...?

Regards
Usman

Comment: I can't understand your question. (RTL_)CRITICAL_SECTION is purely a user-mode type, and SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES is user-mode *and* Win32 only. "Block extraction" is no solution, because if a structure is embedded in another structure, you can't just remove it. If you have a pointer to a structure, simply replace it with `void *` or something.

Comment: We can skip extraction for that type. If we have complete list of kernel objects(i.e user-mode and Win32 kernel types), We can restrict  extraction of that type which was matched from that list.(i.e list which contains kernel user-mode types).

Comment: You're making no sense here. There are no symbols for "Win32 kernel types", and there are no "kernel user-mode types". What are you trying to do, and more importantly why?

Comment: wj: Actually I am implementing a Testing Automation framework (function driven testing). This is totally and entirely different from that framework which we might observed as PUnit or NUnit(these requires code to write in order to test something).Additonal details I will not specify here as that would be huge list. 
In short I need to call methods at RUNTIME.by just picking method from GUI and binding it with some data set and need to call it finally. I need to interact with some GUI(not with code), where every function signature would be shown. I will one of them and command to execute.

Comment: This would be runtime calling not compile time.For this I need complete extracted functions(whole signature) list. Now that signature would might contain some user defined data type as object for parameter. that require to fill that object with some data at runtime. I am doing this with creating nameless block via malloc reffered with void* and then filling that block with some data.Now If here corresponding object having kernel level object like (say CRITICAL_SECTION), I would NOT make that kernel level object at runtime and bind that object with data.

Comment: Again, a critical section is NOT a kernel-related object. It is completely user-mode. Can you give an example of a function/structure for which you don't want to extract certain types? What makes you think the function will still work correctly if you do not fill in the structure correctly (including *all* types)?

Comment: @wj32 : If u give me u'r mail id..that would be nice to elaborate there in precise and more understandable manner.

Comment: @Usman: No, if you want answers, then answer my questions first.

Answer (score 0):

Check the latest docs for [Windows kernel dev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)